# Code doesn't work as desired without signaling with Wait and Pulse

Tags: c#, multithreading

Given the following code, the blocking-condition is changing when I hit the Enter key:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly object _locker = new object();
    static bool _go;
    static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(Work).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        lock (_locker)
        { 
            _go = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(_locker);
        }
    }
    static void Work()
    {
        lock (_locker)
            while (!_go)
                Monitor.Wait(_locker);
        Console.WriteLine("Woken!!!");
    }
}
```

But if I don't use `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` then `Console.WriteLine("Woken!!!");` never been called, it's seems like the `_go` flag is not changing.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: There's an excellent ( and free ) ebook about threading here: [`Albahari`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_go is never changed without Monitor.Wait becasue thread Work method locks _locker and that's why the main thread cannot acquire the same lock in order to change _go value

Comment: Any alternatives for the `Monitor` methods?

Comment: AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent or Semaphore - it depends on your needs. The last one is a better choice if you need to create "multiple notifications".

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Pulse` to wake up the work thread if it is in `Monitor.Wait`

I wrote an article about the correct way to use `Wait` and `Pulse`:

[`Thread synchronization: Wait and Pulse demystified`](http://simplygenius.net/Article/WaitPulse)

Comment: Thank you, I'll read it. It's nice to see that you wrote about it, I couldn't find any really good documentation about this subject in the web.